# If on small device replace iframe with error text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have content in an iframe on my website that doesn't look good on small screens*. It overlaps the edge of the page. I don't want users to use the iframe content, and I want it to be changed to an image based error message (see below). I know about media queries, and I think they might have something to do with the solution. Maybe `display: none`? Or maybe JavaScript/jQuery show/hide functions? Here is my code so far...

```
<iframe id="content" width="485" height="402" frameborder="0" src="http://www.google.com/" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I would like the error message to be...

```
<img id="error" src="error.png" width="100%" alt="Error text goes here" title="Error Message">

<p>This content is not available on small screens like yours. Change to a bigger screen to see the content.</p>
```

By the way, I know that iframes are depreciated in HTML5, but they are the only way to display the content I need on my website.
*I define a 'small screen' as a browser size less than 725px in width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using media Queries:

```
.hide-small {
        display: block
    }
.show-small {
        display: none
    }
@media screen and (max-width: 725px) {
    .hide-small {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .show-small {
        display: block!important
    }
}
```

Using jquery 
in html body

```
$(window).ready(function(){
if ($( window ).width() > 750) {
  $('.hide-small').show();
  $('.show-small').hide();
} else{
  $('.hide-small').hide();
  $('.show-small').show();
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="hide-small"><iframe></div>
<div class="show-small">Text for small screen</div>
```

Personally media query looks better to me, but question has Javascript and jquery tags and its possible to do it with javascript.
EDIT: adjusted width restriction

Answer (score 0):

Add this into header: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Then this is the code:

```css
#moblie {display: none;}
@media screen and (max-width : 725px ){
 #moblie {display: inline-block;}
 #iframe {display: none;}
}
```

```html
<div id="iframe">
<iframe width="485" height="402" frameborder="0" src="http://www.google.com/" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="moblie">
<p>This content is not available on small screens like yours. Change to a bigger screen to see the content.</p>
</div>
```